# What is the cheaper way to get file names in a folder in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-consumption

I'm trying to find a way which consume less memory to get file names from a folder.

I tried these two methods (both works), but I don't know which is cheaper:

```
        string[] files;

        //method 1
        files = new DirectoryInfo(root)
            .GetFiles()
            .Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();

        //method 2
        files = Directory.GetFiles(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
```

Comment: If you use Visual Studio you can use [memory profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage). Even the free Community version contains it.

Comment: Relevant reading regarding "which is faster" questions: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @BJMyers the OP asked which is cheaper, not which is faster. So the [performance-rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) doesn't apply here. You might want to search for an efficiency-rant.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: True, but the core points of the performance rant apply to all kinds of micro-optimization.

Comment: @Heinzi IMHO when people are coming here and ask their first question about something, we shouldn't welcome them by throwing rants on them. If we don't find interesting what they are asking, we can just move on to the next question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I see your point. In this case, however, I didn't get the impression that OP was "ranted at". BJ just posted a link to an insightful article on Eric's blog which might be helpful to OP. It just happens that this article is written in the style of a rant. I'm quite sure that this was intentional (probably for didactic/rhetoric reasons - Eric also sometimes uses the style of a dialog) and not meant to offend anyone. Note that the question did not receive any downvotes - it is an interesting question, after all.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: In addition, note that the rand ends with: *"Well, that rant used up this whole episode. Next time on FAIC: Which is faster, `Nullable<T>.Value` or `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()`?"*, using irony to indicate that the "rant" should be taken with a grain of salt and that - notwithstanding all the valid points raised in the rant - such questions are still interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of those two. Both create an in-memory array containing all file names.

If memory is **really** that scarce (hint: it usually isn't), you can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0) to iterate through all the file names without keeping the whole list in memory:

```
foreach(var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    // do whatever needs to be done with that file name
}
```

Comment: "(hint: it usually isn't)". I couldn't agree more. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*